# preparing data for arulesSequence

Tags: r, arules

I'm struggling with inputes for arulesSequences in R
My data, lets call the dataframe df, looks like this

```
 sequenceID eventID SIZE    event
1           1       1    1   E_351-
2           1       2    1       1-
3           2       1    1   30006+
4           2       2    1   20198+
5           2       3    1     111+
6           2       4    1     610-
7           2       5    1      26+
8           2       6    1   30006-
9           2       7    2 11+, 11
```

the next step as(df,"transactions") gives the following error

> error in asMethod(object) : 
>     can not coerce list with transactions with duplicated items
>   Calls: as ... .nextMethod -> callNextMethod -> .nextMethod -> as -> asMethod

I just spent 2 days trying to just input my data in cspade without success !

Answer (score 2):

After many try-and-fail I managed to convert the file to a transactions object. 
Tricks for those who would struggle the same : 
I had to remove the commas (use paste rather than toString) 
I wrote the table in csv fil : BEAWARE : no header and no rownames or the import with read-baskets will fail. Hope this helps future users.

Comment: Not sure my code is fully understandable, but here is what I did :
    dataLong<-read.table("ECHANT_TLN_SEQ.txt",sep=";",header=TRUE)
    ddSeqless<-data.frame(itemsetID=paste(dataLong$ID,dataLong$ITEMSETS),event=dataLong$EVENEMT)
    ddSeqlessItemsets<-as.data.frame(aggregate(event~itemsetID,data=ddSeqless,FUN=function(x) paste(x,collapse=" ")))
    write.table(ddSeqlessItemsets,"ddSeqlessItemsets.txt",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
    ddSeqlessItemsets.t<-read_baskets(con="ddSeqlessItemsets.txt",info = c("itemsetID","event"))
pm me for further explanation, maybe ?

Comment: I also managed to solve it, I can post it as an answer so the code formatting will be better. Thanks anyways :D

Answer (score 1):

I did it similiar to how you did it. I also included a size column, I saw it in another example, Im not sure what it does though.
My data is bulit like this, but with > 200 000 unique ID.

```
mytxt <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2),
                Time=c(1,2,3,1,2),
                Size=1,
                Event=c("A","B","E", "B","A"))
```

I simply just save it as a txt file with no column or row names.

```
write.table(mytxt, "C:\\mytxt.txt", sep=" ", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

And then I read it with the follwing line

```
data <- read_baskets(con = "C:\\mytxt.txt", info = c("sequenceID","eventID","SIZE"))
```

So it is similiar to what you describe in the comment.

Comment: Well at least, your comment is properly formatted. Would you pm me what you use seq mining for ?

Comment: @GoussuMgoussu I dont think there is any pm function. Howeverm I use it for my master thesis in statistics. If thats what you are asking.

Comment: You are right, no pm on stackexchange. I'm trying to explore sequence mining. Traminer is not itemset oriented, and arulessquences il good but has few algorithms.